Visual Studio setting that controls generated parenthesis behavior
Visual Studio 2022 will regularly delete my closing parenthesis for unexplainable reasons. My relatively new coworker, running the same version as myself, doesn't seem to be experiencing the same problem, but for the life of me I can't find a setting that controls this behavior on my machine.
Below is an example of what it's doing in javascript, though it will do this to me in any language. Note that when I get to the end of my line, I key right to get to the other side of the generated parenthesis and hit ; and I assume it's deleting the parenthesis then. Do I just need to get into the habit of not relying on generated parenthesis? Does anyone know of a setting that controls this?


What is the detailed version of your Visual Studio 2022? If you  enable Insert semicolons at statement ends from Text Editor->JavaScript/TypeScript->Formatting->General and do not hit ";" manually, then format the document, will the issue persists?

I did a quick test on Visual Studio 2022 (17.12.3) and IntelliSense behaves well. For the issue, please try the following to troubleshoot:
1.Switch IntelliSense Completion Mode: You can switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion. To do this, go to Edit > IntelliSense > Switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion or use the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Space. In suggestion mode, only the text you type is inserted into the code.
2.Disable Automatic Brace Completion:  Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript->General->Automatic brace completion and uncheck the option.
3.Resetting Visual Studio settings can resolve unexpected behavior. Go to Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings
For more information, please refer to Reset all settings
4.Please check if you have installed third-party extensions. If so, try disabling them to see if the issue persists. Sometimes, extensions can interfere with IntelliSense functionality.
5.If the issue persists, i would suggest you considering updating your Visual Studio 2022 to the latest version or repair your Visual Studio via Visual Studio Installer.
